# BootsFaces TypeError: minDate() Could not parse date parameter

Tags: datetimepicker, bootsfaces, mindate

I'm using a dateTimePicker with BootsFaces. Here I want to restrict the selection to upcomming days (so no days in the past)

I use bootsfaces version 1.3.0 and omnifaces version 1.7

Here is what I did:

```
<b:dateTimePicker value="startdate" required="true"
minDate="#{now}" colMd="one-fourth"
labelColMd="1" label="Start" format="DD-MM-YYYY" />
```

When I start the xhtml page I get:
TypeError: minDate() Could not parse date parameter: Wed Oct 17 22:39:44 CEST 2018

I also tried to use a String to test if this is working. I added `minDate="10-10-2018"` and got the same Type Error with `parameter: 10-10-2018`

Has anyone an idea what I did wrong?

Comment: I think this is a bug in BootsFaces. Although the documentation states you could use a Date object as min date, it actually only seems to accept String objects. @StephanRauh https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/blob/8c2ec68bda4c85ece0630c2ae1db3b84f7a72426/xtext/BootsFaces.jsfdsl#L705

Comment: I also tried to insert a String but got the same error...

Comment: If you also tried a string, add that to your question. Especially what string value you used (so, basically, provide a [mcve] for your string attempt).

Comment: I've created an issue: https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/1020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found the solution which is working for me.

When I add `minDate="moment()"`it is working.

Comment: You're using a bug to solve the problem... but I'm impressed by how clever your solution is! Plus, I wonder how to fix the bug without breaking your solution. You know, it's elegant. If there was an easy way to tell Java from JavaScript...

Comment: @StephanRauh We could use attribute type detection as I did in slider2 to detect if an Integer or Float is bound to the value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record and to help you follow the current state of the art: We've opened a bug on the [BootsFaces bug tracker](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/1020). Also see the answer of @TheSilent. Until BootsFaces 1.4.0, you can use JavaScript. However, this approach might break when we implement the  bugfix, so proceed with care and be aware of the (small) risk.